Can I recharge Airpods Pro 1 with Airpods Pro 2 Case?
Background: my Airpods Pro 1 charging case has died. Apparently it cannot be recharged.
Problem: Apparently, I cannot buy an original replacement for that case.
Question: Can I buy this one (https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUYG3AM/A/magsafe-charging-case-usb%E2%80%91c-for-airpods-pro-2nd-generation) and use that to recharge my Airpods Pro 1? I know this is sold with compatibility to Airpods Pro 2, but I am asking whether anyone has tried "real-world" to use that with Airpods Pro 1 and if it works.

AirPod Pro 1st gen are still supported. You have to contact Apple Support or Apple Authorized Service Provider and have them order a case as a service part.

It doesn't work. I have both sets of AirPods, and the cases are not compatible.
